# Seeking with FFMPEG at the end of an RTSP stream

Tags: ffmpeg, rtsp

I am using ffmpeg to play RTSP streams in an application.  I have been running into a problem that once I reach the end of an RTSP stream, I am no longer able to see back to anywhere in the stream.

The program I am writing is using LGPL shared libraries, but I can see the same behavior using ffplay using GPL version.

`ffplay.exe "rtsp://184.72.239.149/vod/mp4:BigBuckBunny_115k.mov"`

While the video is playing, I can seek forward or backwards using the keyboard shortcuts for ffplay (left / right arrow key).  Once the stream reaches the end, it is not possible and the stream is paused or playing, seeking no longer works.  I see errors in the shared lib, but in ffplay, I do not see errors unless I use the `s` key (which may make sense that I cannot seek).  In other streams, I have seen an issue where the stream is longer than the reported length, and once the extra video is buffered/downloaded, it is not possible to seek.   Any guidance on what is going on here?

Using `ffplay.exe` (also verified with newer build):

```
C:\Users\kealist\Downloads\ffmpeg-20180526-63c4a4b-win64-static\bin>ffplay "rtsp://184.72.239.149/vod/mp4:BigBuckBunny_115k.mov"
ffplay version N-91158-g63c4a4b0d6 Copyright (c) 2003-2018 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 7.3.0 (GCC)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-sdl2 --enable-bzlib --enable-fontconfig --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-zlib --enable-gmp --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libmysofa --enable-libspeex --enable-libxvid --enable-libaom --enable-libmfx --enable-amf --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-cuvid --enable-d3d11va --enable-nvenc --enable-nvdec --enable-dxva2 --enable-avisynth
  libavutil      56. 18.102 / 56. 18.102
  libavcodec     58. 19.104 / 58. 19.104
  libavformat    58. 17.100 / 58. 17.100
  libavdevice    58.  4.100 / 58.  4.100
  libavfilter     7. 24.100 /  7. 24.100
  libswscale      5.  2.100 /  5.  2.100
  libswresample   3.  2.100 /  3.  2.100
  libpostproc    55.  2.100 / 55.  2.100
[udp @ 0000023ce71807c0] 'circular_buffer_size' option was set but it is not supported on this build (pthread support is required)
[udp @ 0000023ce7174ac0] 'circular_buffer_size' option was set but it is not supported on this build (pthread support is required)
[udp @ 0000023ce71a6f40] 'circular_buffer_size' option was set but it is not supported on this build (pthread support is required)
[udp @ 0000023ce7174bc0] 'circular_buffer_size' option was set but it is not supported on this build (pthread support is required)
[rtsp @ 0000023ce717d900] UDP timeout, retrying with TCP 0B f=0/0
Input #0, rtsp, from 'rtsp://184.72.239.149/vod/mp4:BigBuckBunny_115k.mov':
  Metadata:
    title           : BigBuckBunny_115k.mov
  Duration: 00:09:56.48, start: 0.000000, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0: Audio: aac (LC), 12000 Hz, stereo, fltp
    Stream #0:1: Video: h264 (Constrained Baseline), yuv420p(progressive), 240x160, 24 fps, 24 tbr, 90k tbn, 48 tbc
rtsp://184.72.239.149/vod/mp4:BigBuckBunny_115k.mov: error while seeking
rtsp://184.72.239.149/vod/mp4:BigBuckBunny_115k.mov: error while seeking
 596.27 A-V:-32.424 fd=1290 aq=    0KB vq=    0KB sq=    0B f=1/1
```

With `-v trace` I can see that there is a Seek message, but no seeking actually occurs whether it is paused or playing.

```
video: delay=0.000 A-V=0.173265
Seek to 37% ( 0:03:38) of total duration ( 0:09:56)       B f=1/1
Seek to 83% ( 0:08:14) of total duration ( 0:09:56)       B f=1/1
Seek to 57% ( 0:05:42) of total duration ( 0:09:56)       B f=1/1
Seek to 78% ( 0:07:41) of total duration ( 0:09:56)       B f=1/1
Seek to 85% ( 0:08:24) of total duration ( 0:09:56)       B f=1/1
Seek to 92% ( 0:09:06) of total duration ( 0:09:56)       B f=1/1
    Last message repeated 1 times
Seek to 92% ( 0:09:08) of total duration ( 0:09:56)       B f=1/1
    Last message repeated 1 times
 597.08 A-V:-34.561 fd= 312 aq=    0KB vq=    0KB sq=    0B f=1/1
```

Is there a way to mitigate this without reloading the stream?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug in FFMPEG.  It exists in all players using ffmpeg that I have seen in Windows and OSX.  It is reported [here](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/7815).  For the specific issue I was facing, I had to save/record the stream locally and play the video locally instead of using RTSP playback.